# JavaFX crash when trying to use the "pimaryStage"

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm just learning JavaFX and I'm trying to make a custom title bar that you can move just like the normal one but I'm having trouble not with the moving code itself but with manipulating the window in general.

I'm using **FXML** to manage the layout BTW.

Here's my code:

**Main class**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public Stage mainStage;
    @FXML
    Parent root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.mainStage = primaryStage;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Main.css").toString());
        mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.sizeToScene();
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    Parent root;

    double startX;
    double startY;

    public void exit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Initial:" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY()); //Debug code
        startX = e.getSceneX();
        startY = e.getSceneY();
    }

    @FXML
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Dragged:" + (e.getScreenX() - startX) + "," + (e.getScreenY() - startY)); //Debug code
        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - startX);
            stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - startY);
        }
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<fx:root prefHeight="633.0" prefWidth="1071.0" type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.franga2000.launcher.MainController">
   <children>
      <Pane onMouseDragged="#mouseDragged" onMousePressed="#mousePressed" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="1071.0" styleClass="titlebar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="1019.0" layoutY="9.0" onMouseClicked="#exit" text="Quit" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Even if I try to modifiy the `mainStage` in the main class outside of the `start()` method I always get the same crash:

```
Thread [JavaFX Application Thread] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
    GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run() line: not available [local variables unavailable]    
    GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run() line: not available  
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]    
    GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(View, long, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean, boolean) line: not available    
    WinView(View).handleMouseEvent(long, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean, boolean) line: not available  
    WinView(View).notifyMouse(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean, boolean) line: not available  
    WinApplication._runLoop(String[], Launchable) line: not available [native method]   
    WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication, String[], Launchable) line: not available 
    WinApplication$3$1.run() line: not available    
    Thread.run() line: not available
```

Comment: You're doing something weird with your FXML: you use a "dynamic root" (`<fx:root>`) but don't set the root on the `FXMLLoader`. Try changing `<fx:root>` just to `<AnchorPane>` (don't forget the import, and remove the `type` attribute).

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I was doing a lot of copy-pasting from diffrent sites since it's my first time using JFX. The app copiles fine but I still get the same error when I try to move it

Comment: What error you are facing while you are trying to move it ?

Comment: With the `<fx:root ...>` element replaced with `<AnchorPane prefHeight="633.0" prefWidth="1071.0"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="....MainController" fx:id="root">`, this works fine for me.

Comment: I just copied the opening tag you wrote here and it suddenly works! I must have made a typo or forgot to delet something from you first suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfectly answred by @James_D's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528632/javafx-crash-when-trying-to-use-the-pimarystage#comment39857186_25528632

 Thanks a lot!